# How to plot a vector field using Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

The idea is to plot the following vector field:

[image]

I have two main issue with it:

1) I do not know how to make sure that the arrows are not too long (I know I have to use `length`, but how?).

2) I am told to use `Numpy`to draw the vector field but again, how?

This is what I have tried:

```
# The components of the vector field 
F_x = y*e**x
F_y = x**2 + e**x
F_z = z**2*e**z

# The grid
xf = np.linspace(-0.15, 2.25, 8)
yf = np.linspace(-0.15, 2.25, 8)
zf = np.linspace(-0.75, 2.50, 8)
X_grid, Y_grid, Z_grid = np.meshgrid(xf, yf, zf)

# The arrows; how to deal with them?
dx = 1
#dy = ...
#dz = ...

# Standardize the arrows; In this way all arrows have the same length.
length = np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)
dx_N = dx/length
dy_N = dy/length
dz_N = dz/length

#how to involve numpy in the process??

# Drawing the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.quiver(X_grid, Y_grid, Z_grid, dx_N, dy_N, dz_N, dy, dz, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gnuplot2'))
plt.show()
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

Based on the provided link I tried:

```
from sympy import *
x,y,z = sp.symbols('x y z', real = True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2), np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2), np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2))
F_x = y * exp(x)
F_y = x**2 + exp(x)
F_z = z**2 * exp(z)

# Normalize the arrows:
F_x = F_x / np.sqrt(F_x**2 + F_y**2 + F_z**2)
F_y = F_y / np.sqrt(F_x**2 + F_y**2 + F_z**2)
F_z = F_z / np.sqrt(F_x**2 + F_y**2 + F_z**2)

plt.figure()
plt.title('Vector field')
Q = plt.quiver(x, y, z, F_x, F_y, F_z, units='width')
qk = plt.quiverkey(Q, 0.9, 0.9, 2, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E',
                   coordinates='figure')#I don't understand this line
```

The TypeError: Shape should contain integers only comes up.

The problem is that I don't understand this part of the code:

```
qk = plt.quiverkey(Q, 0.9, 0.9, 2, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E',
                       coordinates='figure')
```

I am still stuck on how to plot this vector field

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44781201/565489) help?

Comment: @Asmus yes thanks. However I would like to have an answer explaining how to deal with arrows and Numpy. I have been looking at code related to plotting vector fields before asking but the problem is that I do not understand most of it.

Comment: `numpy` is not a plotting library, but `matplotlib` is. There are dozens of ways in matplotlib that you could use to plot lines (e.g. `plt.plot( [x0,x1],[y0,y1])` or vectors (e.g. `plot.annotate()` ); `quiver()` just happens to be the most convenient function in case of plotting vector fields, hence I'd suggest using it instead of writing your own plot functions.

Comment: Yes, I am using `quiver()` but I am stuck

Comment: @Asmus I tried to use the info you provided (please see edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you want a 3D quiver, you can check out the [matplotlib tutorial on quiver3D](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/quiver3d.html). And to control the arrow size, check out the [`Axes3d.quiver` library doc](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#quiver), especially the parameters.

A quick snippet:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, .5), np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, .5), np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, .5))

F_x = y * np.exp(x)
F_y = x**2 + np.exp(x)
F_z = z**2 * np.exp(z)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

Q = ax.quiver(x, y, z, F_x, F_y, F_z, length=0.3, normalize=True)
```

But 3d quiver plot can be very crowded! : )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How could we deal with making sure that the arrows are not too long (using `length`, but with what code?)

Comment: I have updated the link to `Axes3d.quiver` library. In this example, with `normalize=True`, we make all arrows have the same length which is `length=XXX`. The unit is the same as axes. Here since each of my arrow is placed .5 apart (from x,y,z) I set the length to be .3. Additionally if you want to control the arrow head size try `arrow_length_ratio`.

Answer (score 1):

The `quiver()` method is a great tool to render vector fields. Since Matplotlib is a two-dimensional plotting library, we need to import the [`mplot3d`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) toolkit to generate a three-dimensional plot.

Here's a good [example](http://dj.megaclique.com/examples/python-plots/3d-vector-field):

Dependencies:
[`Axes3D`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html) for 3D rendering
[`Pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html) to get a MATLAB-like plotting framework
[`Numpy`](https://www.numpy.org)  for numeric-array manipulation

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.25),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.25),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.8))

u = np.sin(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.sin(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
w = (np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.sin(np.pi * z))


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w,
          length=0.15,
          color='Purple'
          )


ax.view_init(elev=10, azim=30)
ax.dist=8

plt.show()
```

[image]