# is there a way to plot a quiverkey without a quiver or hiding the quiver in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am learning this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44781201/11683992).

Here is my code

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([-1, 1])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
Q = ax.quiver(0,0,0,1)
qk = plt.quiverkey(Q, .8, .8, 5, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E',
                   coordinates='figure', color='r')
```

[image: 5]

What I need is only the red one (arrow with label), is there a way to plot the quiverkey without the quiver or with hiding the quiver in matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that comes to my mind is to use `'none'` as the color. Even `color='white'` will do the job but I prefer `'none'`

```
Q = ax.quiver(0,0,0,1, color='none')
qk = plt.quiverkey(Q, .8, .8, 5, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E',
               coordinates='figure', color='r')
```

[image]